# C++ Threads Unexpectedly printing multiple times same line

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, g++

I am writing a program just to see the scheduling of threads by printing something from each thread. What I am getting is some unexpected output.

Although I am updating value of my variable after every print statement in a loop, but output shows print statement executes for multiple times for the same value of variable before updating its value.

**Why it is happening???**

**I am expecting following result,**

```
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444565225,T35,4
```

**but actually I am getting following result.**

```
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
53674444565225,T35,4
```

**Here is my program**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NTHREADS 100
#define MAX_COUNT 1000

using namespace std;
std::ostringstream out1;
ofstream fp1;

pthread_mutex_t     mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

unsigned long long int rdtsc_start(void)
{
   unsigned a, d;
   __asm__ volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));
   return ((unsigned long long)a) | (((unsigned long long)d) << 32);;
}

/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread*/
void *threadA(void *arg)
{ 
    long my_id = (long)arg;
    int check=0;
    volatile long count = 0;
    int j=0;
    while(count++< MAX_COUNT)
    {
        unsigned long long time_x=rdtsc_start();
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        out1<<time_x<<",T"<<my_id<<","<<count<<"\n";
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

        // busy wait  to consume CPU
        volatile long  ii=0;
        while(ii++<50000);
    }
    fp1<<out1.str();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=getpid();

    printf("Thread pid %d\n",pid);

    fp1.open("result_Threaded_Process1.txt"); // in place of parent process 

    pthread_t             threadid[NTHREADS];
    int result;
    //printf("Create %d threads\n", NTHREADS);
    for(long i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) 
    {
        result= pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, threadA, (void *)i);
        if(result ==-1)
        {
            perror("Thread Creation Error: \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }    
    }

    //  printf("Wait for threads and cleanup\n");
    for (long i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);
    }
    fp1.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Where I am making mistakes ? 
Thanks in advance for any clue or hint to understand the output.

I am using g++ under Ubuntu 12.04.

**EDIT**

Accepted answer :

As per @Jason's comment, when I put

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
fp1<<out1.str();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

inside main function I am getting expected result

```
53674444272163,T35,1
53674444562178,T35,2
53674444563927,T35,3
53674444565225,T35,4
```

whereas when I put

```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
   fp1<<out1.str();
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

I am getting the same statement (53674444272163,T35,1 ) printed for NTHREAD times.( 53674444562178,T35,2 ) printed for NTHREAD times.

From my understanding , the output I am getting is for the reason that although every thread write the output value correctly ONLY ONCE ,

`53674444272163,T35,1 
53674444562178,T35,2`

all threads are printing the value of out1 at the time of exit, so in total I am getting same statement printed for NTHREAD times.

Now, my question is why I am not getting (53674444272163,T35,1 ) printed for NTHREAD times without mutex as in my ORIGINAL Program?

Also , sometimes without mutex as per my ORIGINAL program I am getting **26773 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)** , whereas with mutex, Segmentation fault never happened . Why so ???

Thanks .

Comment: Did you try mutex on out1 access?

Comment: Optimizations on? Perhaps `while(ii++<50000);` is optimized out? Not a great way to pass time, regardless. Did you try a sleep instead?

Comment: @crashmstr - that won't be optimised out as `ii` is declared as `volatile`.

Comment: Besides `multiple access` question from @DOUGLASO.MOEN, I have multiplied content question to `out1`: it is copied 5000x times to `fp1` and it contains outputs from many threads - is that by design or this is mistake you are searching for?

Comment: Maybe `out1` should be local variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate your results on my box (4 cores), but I found a few things:

1. You're printing the result of out1 NTHREAD times (at the end of the thread).  You should only print out the value of out1 after all the threads have completed (in main(), after pthread_joins)
2. You're not putting a mutex on out1 when you read it for printing to fp1.  This doesn't matter if you take suggestion #1 but I thought I'd point it out for education purposes.

I think #1 is your problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jason for answering. I have switched off all other cores. Also I am printing the result of out1 for each thread only at the time of exit of a thread. I agree with you to use mutex for out1 also, but not understand what is the reason to move the printing statement out of threadA() function to main. If the same statement printed NTHREAD times, then I must got 53674444565225,T35,1 NTHREAD times which I am not getting, I am only getting 4-6 times and that no also changing with different run.

Comment: I will use mutex with out1 and let you know the result

Comment: when I use, mutex; out1 ;mutex inside threadA function, then I got the result as you said-  53674444565225,T35,1 NTHREAD times.

When I use mutex; out1 ;mutex inside main function OR only ou1 (without using mutex),I am getting expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a pointer to 'i' to a thread which is spinning up.  This is going to be changing as your loops start up.  I would have expected strange behaviours to be a little different from what you see, but try changing the id you pass in to be new for each create_thread call... like this:

```
    for(long i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) 
    {
        int *id = new int;
        *id = i;
        result= pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, threadA, (void *)id);
        if(result ==-1)
        {
            perror("Thread Creation Error: \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }    

    }
```

What this does is create new memory for each thread's id and ensures the value will not be changed by your for loop in main, and also is not accessable by other threads.

Comment: I see what you're thinking, but that's not the case here.  I went back when I read yours thinking "How could I have missed that?" :-).  However, the OP is casting the loop variable 'i' to a void* pointer, not taking the address of 'i', nor is the OP dereferencing the pointer.  Therefore, i is being passed by value.  The my_id variable in the threadA function is reading a copy of the loop variable and is therefore correct.

Comment: You're right.. good call.  My answer is not helpful at all ;)